# Class type as key in map in Scala

Tags: class, scala, types, dictionary

My game has

```
class Enemy
```

who's AI/functionality I can change with

```
trait Moving
trait VerticalMover extends Moving
trait RandomMover extends Moving
```

and so on. Now I need to fetch preloaded stuff based on trait. What I would like to do is have a Map that accepts all traits that extend Moving as keys and then some EnemyContainer as value that would have trait related content preloaded.

But how do I define such a Map and how do format my .get() to get the container by an instance of some Enemy. Something like:

```
val myEnemy = new Enemy with RandomMover 
val myDetails:EnemyContainer = enemyDetailsStore.get(myEnemy.getClass)
```

Comment: Do you mean that you want the `enemyDetailsStore` to return one thing if `myEnemy` extends `VerticalMover`, and another thing if it extends `RandomMover`?  What if it extends both?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. But I'm starting to wonder for the sanity of my whole idea. Maybe I should just have some key string embedded in traits and use that as the key. So with trait linearization the last overriding trait would set the EnemyContainer in other words the textures used to display the enemy.

Comment: Most of the time, the point of a trait/interface is to say "I know how to do *X*", while allowing different implementations of X.  In the absence of other details, I would have thought the most natural design would be to have the `Moving` trait have some kind of `getMovingStrategy` or `move` method on it directly, which you can implement accordingly in the vertical and random mover subtraits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, I assume that your enemy details store is of type `Map[Class[_ <: Moving], EnemyDetails]`. I suspect that something like:

```
//gives a Map[Class[_ <: Moving], EnemyDetails] for all matching keys
enemyDetailsStore.filterKeys(_ isInstance myEnemy)
```

Or:

```
//Iterable[EnemyDetails]
enemyDetailsStore collect { case (c, d) if c isInstance myEnemy => d }
```

Or even just:

```
//Option[EnemyDetails]
enemyDetailsStore collectFirst { case (c, d) if c isInstance myEnemy => d }
```

Will do for you. The only "issue" with this code is that it's O(N), in that it requires a traversal of the map, rather than a simple lookup, which would be O(1), or O(log N)

Answer (score 13):

Maybe you could wrap a Map[Manifest, Any] ensuring that the values corresponds to the manifest keys.

Possible sketch of that. First a little helper

```
class Typed[A](value: A)(implicit val key: Manifest[A]) {
  def toPair: (Manifest[_], Any) = (key, value)
}
object Typed {
  implicit def toTyped[A: Manifest](a: A) = new Typed(a)
  implicit def toTypable[A](a: A) = new {
    def typedAs[T >: A : Manifest] = new Typed[T](a)(manifest[T])
  }
}
```

then the wrapper itself (which is not a map)

```
class TypedMap private(val inner: Map[Manifest[_], Any]) {
  def +[A](t: Typed[A]) = new TypedMap(inner + t.toPair)
  def +[A : Manifest](a: A) = new TypedMap(inner + (manifest[A] -> a))
  def -[A : Manifest]() = new TypedMap(inner - manifest[A])
  def apply[A  : Manifest]: A = inner(manifest[A]).asInstanceOf[A]
  def get[A : Manifest]: Option[A] = inner.get(manifest[A]).map(_.asInstanceOf[A])
  override def toString = inner.toString
  override def equals(other: Any) = other match {
    case that: TypedMap => this.inner == that.inner
    case _ => false
  }
  override def hashCode = inner.hashCode
}

object TypedMap {
  val empty = new TypedMap(Map())
  def apply(items: Typed[_]*) = new TypedMap(Map(items.map(_.toPair) : _*))
}
```

With that you can do

```
import Typed._
val repository = TypedMap("foo", 12, "bar".typedAs[Any])
```

> repository: TypedMap = Map(java.lang.String -> foo, Int -> 12, Any ->
>   bar)

You retrieve elements with

```
repository[String] // returns "foo"
repository.get[Any] // returns Some("bar")
```

I think the private constructor should ensure that the _`asInstanceOf` is safe. `inner` may be left public, as it is immutable. This way, the rich interface of `Map` will be available, but unfortunately, not to create another `TypedMap`.